# Fastest way to retrieve raster layers for a given year from a list of SpatRaster objects and to calculate the mean across these layers

Tags: r, list, terra

I am creating a function to retrieve raster layers for a given year from a list of SpatRaster objects and to calculate the mean across these layers. Each SpatRaster has 94 raster layers. The problem is that my function is too slow. Is there a solution to speed up my code? Here is a reproducible example with SpatRaster objects of 12 rasters:

Example data, a list of SpatRaster objects

```
m <- terra::rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, nl=12, 
     names=paste0("year_", 2010:2021), vals=rep(1:100, 12))

m_list <- list()
for (variable in c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7")){
    for (scenario in c("s1", "s2")){
        for (model_type in c("mod1", "mod2", "mod3", "mod4")){
            m_list[[variable]][[scenario]][[model_type]] <- m
        }
    }
}
```

Create the function

```
calculateMeanAcrossRasters <- function(raster_layers, year_range){
  
  ## Create a list containing models
  model_list <- list()
  mean_raster_layer <- list()
  
  ## Loop over the years
  for (year in seq(year_range[1], year_range[2], 1)) { 
    ## Loop over the rasters
    for(raster_layer in 1:length(raster_layers)){
      ## Retrieve the raster layer for a given year
      model_list[[names(raster_layers)[raster_layer]]][[paste0("year_", year)]] <- 
        subset(raster_layers[[raster_layer]], 
        names(raster_layers[[raster_layer]]) %in% c(paste0("year_", year)))
    } 
    ## Calculate the mean
    mean_raster_layer[[paste0("year_", year)]] <- 
         terra::app(terra::rast(do.call(c, model_list)), 
             fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE) 
  }
  ## Return a raster
  return(mean_raster_layer)
}
```

Apply the function

```
test <- list()
variables <- c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7")
## Loop over the variables
for (variable in variables) {
  writeLines(paste0("Variable: ", variable)) 
  test[[variable]] <- lapply(m_list[[variable]], 
        FUN = function(x) { 
           calculateMeanAcrossRasters(raster_layers = x, year_range = c(2010, 2021))
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this instead

```
test <- list()
for (variable in names(m_list)) {
  test[[variable]] <- lapply(m_list[[variable]], \(x) app(sds(x), mean))
}
```

I did not bother to subset the years here as in the example you use them all anyway.

I also think that you created a problem for yourself by creating that list. It would be much easier to work with a vector of filenames. From that, you can create a vector that has the unique combination of variable and scenario. You can then use that as the index in a single call to `tapp`.